# How can I push project in specific folder in my GitHub repository?

Tags: eclipse, git, github, egit

I have created a new repository in GitHub named "EpamCourses2015". Next I created folder within it named "homeworks". There is only one URI `"https://github.com/username/EpamCourses2015.git"`, so in my EGit plugin in eclipse I added "homeworks" myself, like `"https://github.com/username/EpamCourses2015.git/homeworks"` but it gives me an error when I add in ref mappings:

> Transport Error: Cannot get remote repository refs.
>   https://github.com/username/EpamCourses2015.git/homeworks:
>   https://github.com/username/EpamCourses2015.git/homeworks/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack
>   not found

Any one can tell me please, how can I push my projects into separate folder in my GitHub repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Github isn't designed to be used like that really, you can only clone and push your parent repository into Github and subrepositories are not properly supported.

You should clone your EpamCourses2015 repository, add your homeworks folder into that, commit it and then push that to Github

If you wish to do this inside Eclipse, clone the EpamCourses2015 repository and create your homeworks project inside that folder, Eclipse should automatically detect the parent repository and allow you to add it